# Greedy Algorithm in JAVA. Implementation issues

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, io, greedy

I have to develop a project in which I have to use greedy algorithm. The purpose of using greedy to select the best node.

My project detail. I have a server in GUI in which I have to send some data to 8 clients. So using greedy I have to send to the best 2 nodes. This best 2 nodes are selected on the connectivity with other nodes and its path weight.I know what are greedy algorithms but not having idea how to implement it in java according to my project. How to select the best nodes. My idea is storing the nodes information like connectivity,total number of bytes sent in the data base and using greedy to select the best. Can you guide me which is best greedy Algo to do this?

Thanks Ameer

Comment: You need to clarify this question, it's not obvious what you are asking. Tell us the algorithm, show us what you've done so far and what your problems are.

Comment: Also, if this is for homework, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: You can use evolutionary approach.. initially send the signal to nodes with equal greediness or use some heuristics. After sending few times, based upon the time it took, or some other global states you can change the greediness weightage of a node.

Comment: @AlexFlorescu I am  not yet started want guidance. Just help me. I will post the code If you guide me. thanks

Comment: Anyone having any idea to guide me

Comment: You need to go into more detail as to how to define one node as better than another. Is it the sum of shortest paths to other nodes, the max, or something else? And how do you combine this with the shortest path to that node? **However**, any scenario seems like multiple single-source shortest path problems (solvable using Dijkstra or Bellman-Ford) (or possibly all-pairs shortest path, solvable with Floyd-Warshall). **@AlexFlorescu** [The homework tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).